# is there a way in NIPA accounts to see a measure of size/change in private debt stock?

Tags: macroeconomics, debt, saving

is there a way in NIPA accounts to see a measure of size/change in private debt stock , and how is it measured?
if not then how is it measured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [Flow of Funds](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/z1/current/) (which measures transactions and levels of assets and liabilities), not the National Income and Product Accounts, which primarily measure output and (mostly, though not entirely, physical) capital stock.

Comment: many thanks, i suppose the size of householder debt, and corporate debt is measured simply by adding up their loans from banks , and bonds outstanding for the latter ?

Comment: For consumers, it’s a combination of bank loans, mortgages and consumer credit (which don’t all come from banks, and “other” loans (mostly from government, especially student loans).

Comment: For corporates, it’s a much longer list, including things you wouldn’t necessarily think of off the top of your head, like pension liabilities. You can see it in the levels table: https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/DisplayTable.aspx?t=l.103